# JQuery toggleClass parent and children

Tags: jquery, toggleclass

I'm just getting to know Javascript and JQuery and I can't figure this out: Is there a shorter way for this:

```
$(".toggle").click(function(){
$(this).parent().toggleClass("collapsed");
$(this).parent().children().toggleClass("collapsed");
$(this).parent().next(".abcContent").toggle(0);
```

I'm glad I got it to work after all but surely this isn't how it's done properly... I want to toggle the parent class (abcTitle) including its children (i.e. button).

```
<div class="abcTitle">
<div class="abcButton toggle"></div>
<h4 class=toggle>Title</h4><div class="sortable"></div>
</div>
<div class="abcContent">Content</div>
```

Thanks for enlightening me!

For clarification here's some relevant CSS

```
.abcButton {
    background-image:url(minus.png);
}
.abcButton.collapsed {
    background-image:url(plus.png); 
}
.abcTitle {
    border-top-left-radius:14px;
}
.abcTitle.collapsed {
    border-bottom-left-radius:14px;
}
```

So basically a click on either abcButton or H4 is supposed to trigger the collapse of abcContent while adding class .collapsed to both abcButton and abcTitle.
(Btw, If I could figure out how to exclude

```
<div class="sortable"></div>
```

from the click function I could just make abcTitle my click handler with no need to seperate abcButton and h4)

Comment: If you're trying to show/hide all the different elements on the same level, wouldn't it be easier to hide a container that contains them?

Comment: Not sure if that's what I want to do... I'm trying to hide/show one element while adding classes to some others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should cache, or chain, your jQuery object; `$(this).parent()` is being calculated 3 times.

```
$(".toggle").click(function(){
    var self = $(this).parent();

    self.toggleClass("collapsed");
    self.children().toggleClass("collapsed");
    self.next(".abcContent").toggle(0);
```

You shouldn't need to add the `collapsed` class to your children elements; you CSS should work out that the elements are collapsed from the fact the parent has the class of collapsed.

```
div.abcTitle h4 {
    /* Styles when the element is shown */
}

div.abcTitle.collapsed h4 {
    /* Styles when the element is collapsed */
}
```

You can probably guarantee that the next element will always be the `abcContent`, so you shouldn't need to worry about selecting the next element.

If you are toggling a number of elements, it'll be better to use the [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate) or [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live) methods, which utilize the event bubbling mechanisms of JavaScript; the event handler is only bound to one element, rather than all of them, increasing performance.

Having said all of that, a better solution might be as follows:

```
$(document).delegate('.toggle', 'click', function () {
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('collapsed').next().toggle();
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! "Chaining" works great (if indeed by var self = $(this); you mean var self = $(this).parent() Your "better solution" also works with the exeption that toggleClass only works on abcTitle but doesn't work on abcButton. Probably something wrong with my css...

Comment: @Tim: Whoops, I did indeed mean `var self = $(this).parent()`. Glad to hear it helps.

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

$(".clickclassname").click(function(){ 

$("body").toggleClass("addclassname"); 
}); 

});
```